# C# string.Join with muliple delimiter

Tags: c#, string

I searched through Google and all the other links, but couldn't find out if this is possible.

`string.Join` method link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx

`Join(String, String[])` , I understand that the first argument (`String`) is the delimiter and the second argument (`String[]`) is the array which we want to join. Is it possible to join it with 2 different string/delimiter? 
for e.g. my array>

```cs
array[0] = A;
array[1] = Alpha; 
array[2] = B; 
array[3] = Bravo;
```

such than the end product is:

```
A = Alpha, B= Bravo,
```

So it will be 2 strings, "=" and ",". Any suggestion to do this?

Comment: Have you considered whether to redesign your array into a two-dimensional array? Judging by the data you provide it doesn't really seem to fit it's current one-dimensional structure.

Comment: Consider putting your config in a 2D format e.g. a `Dictionary<string, string>`. Your code will become much less error prone and much more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPADTED: Both Codes** if you don't want `,` at end.

You can do like this, But suggested to pair `key` and `value` or use 2-dimensional array.

**CODE:**

```
int i=0;
string str = "";
var arr = new string[] { "A", "Alpha", "B", "Bravo" };

foreach (var item in arr)
 {
    str += item;
    if (i < arr.Length-1)
    {
       if (i % 2 == 0)                
         str += " = ";               
       else
         str += ", ";          
    }
    i++;
 }
//output: A = Alpha, B = Bravo
```

---

By this way you can also use for multiple delimiters.

**Example:**

```
int i=0;
string str = "";
var arr = new string[] { "A", "Alpha", "1", "B", "Bravo", "2" };

var delimiters = new string[] { " = ", ", ", ":" };

foreach (var item in arr)
 {
    str += item;
    if (i < arr.Length-1)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
           str += delimiters[0];
        else if (i % 3 == 1)
           str += delimiters[1];                        
        else
           str += delimiters[2];                        
     }
     i++;
 }
//output: A = Alpha:1, B = Bravo:2
```

Comment: if at the final output I don't wish to have the , ? How should I edit the code? I tried lots of method but not very sucessful.

Answer (score 3):

You need to group your values pair-wise, use `string.Join` on each pair (or just use `key + " = " + value`) and then use `string.Join` on the results.

`String.Join` doesn't support this functionality out of the box.

Alternatively, you could just write your own loop to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. You could just `Join` on the `,` and then loop through and replace every other `,` with a `=`.

Answer (score 1):

This extensions method should do the trick:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Join(this object[] array, string[] delimiters)
    {
        var returnString = "";
        var s = new Queue<string>(delimiters);
        for (var i = 0; i < array.Count(); i++)
        {
            var delim = s.Dequeue();
            returnString += array[i] + delim;
            s.Enqueue(delim);
        }
        while (s.Count > 0) returnString = returnString.TrimEnd(s.Dequeue().ToCharArray());
        return returnString;

    }
}
```

You can then use `array.Join(new string[] {"=", ","})`
The extension-method alternates between the delimiters.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
 StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

 for(int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)
 {
         output.Append(array[i] + "=" + array[i+1]);
         if(i != array.length) output.Append(",");
 }

 Response.Write(output.ToString());
```

Comment: If a final "," needs entering on the last item, then yes, take out the if statement - but if "A = Alpha, B = Bravo" needs echoing out, then the above code will achieve the desired effect.

Comment: please test it first, I see at least 3 errors.  I think you need i+=2 and different conditions in the for and if.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you're looking for ;)

```
string[] str = { "A", "Alpha", "B", "Beta" };
string[] dl = { " = ", ", " };
string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    result += str[i] + dl[0] + str[i + 1];
    if(i != str.Length - 2){
        result += dl[1];
    }
    i++;
}
return result;
```

^^

Answer (score 0):

@javed with for the code is a bit simpler

```
            for (int i = 0; i < query.Length; i++)
            {
                endpoint += query[i];

                if (i < query.Length - 1)
                {
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                        endpoint += "=";
                    else
                        endpoint += "&";
                }
            }
```