# Replace every other of a certain char in a string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have searched a lot to find a solution to this, but could not find anything. I do however suspect that it is because I don't know what to search for.

First, I have a string that I convert to an array. The string will be formatted like so:

```
"99.28099822998047,68.375 118.30699729919434,57.625 126.49999713897705,37.875 113.94499683380127,11.048999786376953 96.00499725341797,8.5"
```

I create the array with the following code:

```
    public static Array StringToArray(string String)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        string[] Coords = String.Split(' ', ',');
        foreach (string Coord in Coords)
        {
            list.Add(Coord);
        }
        var array = list.ToArray();
        return array;
    }
```

Now my problem is; I am trying to find a way to convert it back into a string, with the same formatting. So, I could create a string simply using:

```
    public static String ArrayToString(Array array)
    {
        string String = string.Join(",", array);
        return String;
    }
```

and then hopefully replace every 2nd "," with a space (" "). Is this possible? Or are there a whole other way you would do this?

Thank you in advance! I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: `StringToArray(string String)` - change your parameter name, it's *very* misleading when it comes to `String.Split(...)`.

Comment: Umm... for the first function, couldn't you just write `String.Split(' ', ',');` instead of getting an array, converting it to a list, and then converting it *back* to an array?

Comment: just use the input string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# string.Join with muliple delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430554/c-sharp-string-join-with-muliple-delimiter)

Comment: you doing this whole excercise to replace certain characters in it?

Comment: @Doorknob Sure I could. But I am really new in C#, so I am sure I am not doing it the most optimal way.

Comment: I think everyone's unclear on why you don't just use the input string if that is what you need.

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso That is not possible.

Comment: @JustCode I am doing this exercise because my system gets a string as input, but I need it as an array. But, I also need later on to retrieve the array from the database, and pass it back as a string in the same format again.

Comment: post the exercise as well so we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way of doing what you need. However, it's pretty trivial to achieve what it is you need e.g.

```
public static string[] StringToArray(string str)
{
    return str.Replace(" ", ",").Split(',');
}

public static string ArrayToString(string[] array)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length-1; i++)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat(i % 2 != 0 ? "{0} " : "{0},", array[i]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I did something simulair to this (based on the link from rr-). Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

If those are pairs of coordinates, you can start by parsing them like pairs, not like separate numbers:

```
public static IEnumerable<string[]> ParseCoordinates(string input)
{
    return input.Split(' ').Select(vector => vector.Split(','));
}
```

It is easier then to reconstruct the original string:

```
public static string PrintCoordinates(IEnumerable<string[]> coords)
{
    return String.Join(" ", coords.Select(vector => String.Join(",", vector)));
}
```

But if you absolutely need to have your data in a flat structure like array, it is then possible to convert it to a more structured format:

```
public static IEnumerable<string[]> Pairwise(string[] coords)
{
    coords.Zip(coords.Skip(1), (coord1, coord2) => new[] { coord1, coord2 });
}
```

You then can use this method in conjunction with `PrintCoordinates` to reconstruct your initial string.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is indeed coordinates, but at the moment I have to use them in a 1D array. But I will definitely look into parsing them as pairs, since it would make more sense, and would be easier to understand. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a route to do it. I don't think other solutions were removing last comma or space. I also include a test.

```
public static String ArrayToString(Array array)
{
    var useComma = true;
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var value in array)
    {
        if (useComma)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", value, ",");
        }
        else
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", value, " ");
        }

        useComma = !useComma;
    }

    // Remove last space or comma
    stringBuilder.Length = stringBuilder.Length - 1;

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}

[TestMethod]
public void ArrayToStringTest()
{
    var expectedStringValue =
        "99.28099822998047,68.375 118.30699729919434,57.625 126.49999713897705,37.875 113.94499683380127,11.048999786376953 96.00499725341797,8.5";
    var array = new[]
        {
            "99.28099822998047",
            "68.375",
            "118.30699729919434",
            "57.625",
            "126.49999713897705",
            "37.875",
            "113.94499683380127",
            "11.048999786376953",
            "96.00499725341797",
            "8.5",
        };

    var actualStringValue = ArrayToString(array);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedStringValue, actualStringValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
string inputString = "1.11,11.3 2.22,12.4 2.55,12.8";
List<string[]> splitted = inputString.Split(' ').Select(a => a.Split(',')).ToList();
string joined = string.Join(" ", splitted.Select(a => string.Join(",",a)).ToArray());
```

"splitted" list will look like this:

> 1.11     11.3
>
> 2.22     12.4
>
> 2.55     12.8

"joined" string is the same as "inputString"

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach to this problem.

```
    public static string ArrayToString(string[] array)
    {
        Debug.Assert(array.Length % 2 == 0, "Array is not dividable by two.");

        // Group all coordinates as pairs of two.
        int index = 0;
        var coordinates = from item in array
                          group item by index++ / 2
                              into pair
                              select pair;

        // Format each coordinate pair with a comma.
        var formattedCoordinates = coordinates.Select(i => string.Join(",", i));

        // Now concatinate all the pairs with a space.
        return string.Join(" ", formattedCoordinates);
    }
```

And a simple demonstration:

```
    public static void A_Simple_Test()
    {
        string expected = "1,2 3,4";
        string[] array = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
        Debug.Assert(expected == ArrayToString(array));
    }
```